# pthread mutex: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol c++

Tags: c++, locking, pthreads

I'm obtaining this link error and I cannot find the solution. Can you maybe put me in the right direction where to search for it?
I get: **error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_pthread_mutex_lock referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall**... here comes the whole name of my function with parameters. 
**pthread_mutex_lock** and **pthread_mutex_unlock** are used in this function (not as arguments).
Including "pthread.h" doesn't change anything.

Comment: That error code seems to come from the MSVC compiler, yet windows has no native support for pthreads. So you should tell us a bit more about your environment and what you're trying to do, and perhaps show the code that results in this linker error.

Comment: Where did you get `pthread.h` from?  It's not part of MSVC, so you had to acquire it from somewhere else.  You'll need to specify the pthread library to link in the Visual Studio project (or on the command line if you're not using the IDE).  If you need more details, the `pthread-win32` package from http://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/index.html may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pthread` library is for POSIX systems (Linux, BSD, Mac OS). You indicated that you're on Visual Studio in Windows - if you are looking to do multithreading on Windows, see [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Better yet, if you can use more recent tools, C++11 offers [built-in threading functionality](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread).

Answer (score 3):

I used pthread-win32 available from [sourceware.org/pthreads-win32](https://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/).

I've been facing this issue for couple hours now and was finally able to fix it by adding the 'lib', 'include' and 'bin' folder content provided with the download, in the appropriate folders in Visual Studio dependency installation folder.

Mine is in

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017"

Then i added the library dependency 'pthreadVC2.lib;' in

> Project -> Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependancies

And voila! pthreads started to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
-lpthread
```

or

```
-lthread
```

to your compiler command line (depending on OS and compiler)

UPDATE: @nos correctly points out that this seems to be a MS linker error.  You shouldn't be using pthreads in Visual Studio.  Windows Threading API is very different.

Comment: I use Visual C++ '08, on Windows XP 32bits. I was now reading shortly about running from CL, because I'm not familiar with that. How can I actually add this line you mentioned, if I by now run my program with simple run button? I'm new in this idea.

Comment: how is that the code was running previously without errors? after my try to merge it with another one, I get this problem. What comes to my mind is that somehow this part of the code where threading is included, was not active under some conditions ... is it the only reasonable thinking, or is there some other way?

Comment: If you're in `gcc`, the correct flag is `-pthread`. `-lpthread` doesn't work on all distros (such as Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling your own shared library, the problem is that you've defined DLL_EXPORT or put -DDLL_EXPORT on your compile line.  Deep (system) dependencies are triggering on this macro and defining these __imp__blah_blah symbols.

PROBLEM:

```
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -c xxx.cpp  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/xxx.o

$ nm .libs/libnexa_la-random2.o | grep pthread
                 U __imp_pthread_mutex_destroy
                 U __imp_pthread_mutex_init
                 U __imp_pthread_mutex_lock
                 U __imp_pthread_mutex_unlock
```

WORKING (these will resolve when linked with pthreads):

```
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -c xxx.cpp -DPIC -o .libs/xxx.o

$ nm .libs/libnexa_la-random2.o | grep pthread
                 U pthread_mutex_destroy
                 U pthread_mutex_init
                 U pthread_mutex_lock
                 U pthread_mutex_unlock
```

If this an autoconf project, you need to get the declaration of this flag out of libtool.  Here are two ways to do that:

sed -i 's/-DDLL_EXPORT//g' libtool

Or in configure.ac:

lt_cv_prog_compiler_pic="-DPIC"
lt_cv_prog_compiler_pic_CXX="-DPIC"